# Trying to scroll into view a nested scrollbar element's child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to scroll into view a dummy div (id = "bottom"), which is contained inside a nested scrollbar.
But whenever the statement is executed, it just scrolled the main scrollbar (the one on the page it self.)

Below is the code, the mapped element is a list of messages, which rerenders after a new message has been sent. I've kept `document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView();`
Which indeed works but it just scrolls the scrollbar outside the "messageList" div (the main scrollbar of the webpage.).

```
<div className='messageList chatRoomSubContainers'>
                <br />

                {data &&
                  data.map((msg) => {
                    const currentMsg = msg.data();
                    const messageState =
                      currentMsg.uid === currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';
                    return (
                      <ChatBubble
                        key={msg.id}
                        text={currentMsg.text}
                        // Send time stamp as well
                        photo={currentMsg.photo}
                        messageState={messageState}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                <div id='bottom'>dfdsf</div>
              </div>
```

Here is the img ref -

[image: ss]

Answer (score 2):

`scrollIntoView` is a method for `document` only, and can't be applied for a specific element.

You need to measure the distance between the `#button` element, and the top boundary of its parent.

You can use this method for measuring.

```
function scrollParentToChild(parent, child) {
// Where is the parent on page
  var parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  // What can you see?
  var parentViewableArea = {
    height: parent.clientHeight,
    width: parent.clientWidth
  };

  // Where is the child
  var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Is the child viewable?
  var isViewable = (childRect.top >= parentRect.top) && (childRect.bottom <= parentRect.top + parentViewableArea.height);

  // if you can't see the child try to scroll parent
  if (!isViewable) {
        // Should we scroll using top or bottom? Find the smaller ABS adjustment
        const scrollTop = childRect.top - parentRect.top;
        const scrollBot = childRect.bottom - parentRect.bottom;
        if (Math.abs(scrollTop) < Math.abs(scrollBot)) {
            // we're near the top of the list
            parent.scrollTop += scrollTop;
        } else {
            // we're near the bottom of the list
            parent.scrollTop += scrollBot;
        }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I tried combining it with the code, It doesn't works. Can you possibly put up a JS Fiddle or something, so that I can know how to implement it? I just want, to scroll to the #button div on click of a certain button.